# mono: How to change target framework

Tags: .net, mono

How do i change mono to run code made for .NET 4 intead of 2? I'm on Ubuntu Server 11.04

mono --version gives me this:

```
mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 2.6.7 (Debian 2.6.7-5ubuntu3)
Copyright (C) 2002-2010 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  x86
        Disabled:      none
```

Supposedly i need to run mono 2.8 or greater. So i ran [this script (Ubuntu)](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2011/02/mono-2-10-install-script-for-ubuntu-fedora/) and rebooted but it still looks like i have the same version.

**Edit #1:** When i get an error i see this at the bottom:

> Version information: Mono Runtime
> Version: 2.6.7 (Debian
> 2.6.7-5ubuntu3); ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.1433

**Edit #2:**
When i try to install the [mono-parallel 2.10 deb package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5304/upgrading-to-latest-stable-mono) as suggested by skolima's answer and here. I get the following error:

> dpkg: error processing
> mono-2.10.1-parallel-environment.deb
> (--install):  package architecture
> (amd64) does not match system (i386)
> Errors were encountered while
> processing:
> mono-2.10.1-parallel-environment.deb

But i don't see any alternate downloads for i386.

Comment: What happens when you run your application as is?

Comment: This belongs on http://askubuntu.com/ , not here, it's a problem with the distribution you are using.

Comment: @skolima: Not so sure it's a distribution problem. I believe it's a general mono config question because i want to know how to change the target framework which is probably in some mono config somewhere. If you KNOW for a fact that it IS a distribution problem then throw me a bone, please, and i'll move it. Thanks.

Comment: Added an answer, because this was too long for a comment. This is not Mono configuration, just standard behaviour when a tool is installed outside of your `PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

The script you have used installs additional Mono environment in /opt/mono-2.10 . To use it, you would have to follow instructions from http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments . In short:

- create a file ~/mono-2.10-env with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
MONO_PREFIX=/opt/mono-2.10
GNOME_PREFIX=/usr
export DYLD_LIBRARY_FALLBACK_PATH=$MONO_PREFIX/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_FALLBACK_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MONO_PREFIX/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$MONO_PREFIX/include:$GNOME_PREFIX/include
export ACLOCAL_PATH=$MONO_PREFIX/share/aclocal
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$MONO_PREFIX/lib/pkgconfig:$GNOME_PREFIX/lib/pkgconfig
export PATH=$MONO_PREFIX/bin:$PATH
PS1="[mono2.10] \w @ "
```

- source it in your shell

```
source ~/mono-2.10-env
```

and the current shell session will be running the new Mono. Remember that it is installed outside the normal tree, and `apt` will not update it. In general, I'd recommend choosing a distro which provides packages that aren't two years old. Also, this is a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/5304/upgrading-to-latest-stable-mono .

Comment: Thanks, Regarding the duplicate: I tried it before i even posted my questions days ago. However, when trying to install the mono-parallel 2.10 deb package i get an error (... package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386).. ). And it seems there are no alternative files i can use.

Comment: Does this mean i can't use this architecture?

Comment: (+1) Also, what distro would you recommend for mono? As far as easy to update and use and all. Key being EASY. I have no problem starting over with a different distro.

Comment: Urm, you are running an i386 system - why? As for development - my preference lies with Gentoo, as it's very malleable, and it's trivial to keep on the bleeding edge. However, it sometimes _is_ more pain then it's worth - for something more supported, look into openSUSE, it's the OS used by most developers on Mono team.